# Properly perform task / query one table and display multiple rows into one row pr identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains A LOT of rows, with several identifiers that are relevant in the big picture, but in my current task, only  3 columns are important:

```
SiteIdentifier | SysTm | Signalet
```

SiteIdentifier is a number, SysTm is DateTime and Signalet is a text field
Ex data:

```
587451 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | Left
587451 | 2021-03-04 07:12:17 | Joined
214537 | 2021-03-05 02:13:03 | Left
587451 | 2021-03-04 12:12:12 | Left
214537 | 2021-03-05 07:13:00 | Joined
587451 | 2021-03-08 01:04:07 | Joined
```

Here's what I want to achieve:
**I want to create a query that can display:**

```
SiteIdentifier | SysTm of last Signalet Left | SysTm of last Signalet Joined | DATEDIFF(hour, ...  between last Left and Joined
```

In the case of the lines of example data, a result would be:

```
587451 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 07:12:17 | 79
214537 | 2021-03-05 02:13:03 | 2021-03-05 07:13:00 | 5
587451 | 2021-03-04 12:12:12 | 2021-03-08 01:04:07 | 84
```

(*Each SiteIdentifier can be represented NUMEROUS times*)

These rows are all contained in one table, which is what is tripping me up...

I have done a query like:

```
SELECT SiteIdentifier, SysTm, Signalet
FROM Table1
WHERE ((Signalet = 'Left') or (Signalet = 'Joined'))
GROUP BY SiteIdentifier, SysTm, Signalet
ORDER BY SiteIdentifier, SysTm ASC
```

This query would give me every record of Left and Joined, with each Signalet in it's own row. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it display what I want, how I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SiteIdentifier,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Left' THEN SysTM END) as left_tm,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Joined' THEN SysTM END) as Joined_tm,
       DATAEDIFF(hour,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Left' THEN SysTM END),
                 MAX(CASE WHEN Signalet = 'Joined' THEN SysTM END)
                ) as time_diff
FROM Table
WHERE Signalet IN ( 'Left', 'Joined')
GROUP BY SiteIdentifier
ORDER BY SiteIdentifier;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce8e73882097b932e3100b2546f6eb0f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It only shows the Left DateTime, and NULL in both Joined and time_diff... The number of rows it displays is correct however.

Comment: OK, I worked on the GROUP BY clause, and got a result. However, it only shows the latest occurrence, not all of them.
If I try to remove the max() on the Left_tm and Joined_tm - I have to add SysTm and Signalet to the GROUP BY clause, to get it to run... If I add SysTm and Signalet to the GROUP BY, it's back showing NULL in Joined_tm and time_diff

Comment: The error I get if I remove the max(), is ..."invalid because it's not contained in an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause"...

Comment: @Geir . . . The `SELECT` had extra columns that should not be in a `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff] Yes, I got that working yesterday, by doing work on the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` statement. However, this is only returning the MAX / latest record of each unique `SiteIdentifier`. I am trying to get EVERY record of EVERY `SiteIdentifier`

Comment: I added some GROUP BY DATEPART year, month, day and got results, however, if the difference between `Left` and `Joined` is over one day, it displays several NULL records
```
SiteIdentifier Year Month Day left_tm Joined_tm time_diff
214537 2021 3 5 2021-03-05 02:13:03 2021-03-05 07:13:00.000 5
587451 2021 2 1 2021-02-01 00:00:00  
587451 2021 2 4 NULL 2021-02-04 07:12:17 NULL
587451 2021 3 4 2021-03-04 12:12:12 NULL NULL
587451 2021 3 8 NULL 2021-03-08 01:04:07 NULL
```

Comment: @Geir . . . The question asked here has a result set smaller than the input data, suggesting that you want aggregation (or filtering).  I would suggest you ask another question if you want to retain all the rows in your original data.

Comment: @[Gordon Linoff] In the question, I even wrote a few lines of how I wanted the result to look like, with one SiteIdentifier represented twice, and then the rest. I can ask a new question, sure, but I don't know how to ask it differently...